# Problem occur while reading data from excel file and transfer data to list

Tags: python, excel, telegram, telethon

I'm adding users to telegram groud with the help of userid and user hash. All user id and hash are available in excel file. where the problem occurs while I'm reading userid and userhash from excel and transfer it to a list known as id and access_hash. It shows me user id invalid error.
here the code:

```
Name = []
id = []
access_hash = []
Username = []
input_file = input("Enter the path of Excel file:")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(input_file)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
row = 1

for i in range(sheet.nrows - 1):

   column = 0
   Name.append(sheet.cell_value(row, column))
   column += 1

   idtemp = int(sheet.cell_value(row, column))

   id.append(idtemp)
   column += 1

   hashtemp = int(sheet.cell_value(row, column))
   access_hash.append(hashtemp)

   column += 1
   Username.append(sheet.cell_value(row, column))
   row += 1
elif mode == 2:
   user_to_add = InputPeerUser(id[index], access_hash[index])
else:
   sys.exit("Invalid Mode Selected. Please Try Again.")
index += 1

client(InviteToChannelRequest(target_group_entity, [user_to_add]))
```

But while I'm repeating the same process with creating id and user list manually, So it didn't give any error.Like this.

```
Name = ['abcdef', 'zerdfel']
id = [125556777, 1344500000]
access_hash = [1418916639566525455, 70732418082029882900]
Username = ['qwert', 'tyuuygj']
```

So I think while I'm reading usersid and userhash from excel and transfer them to list, So during this process a problem occur but I don't know about the problem and what problem occur here because it didn't shows any error.

Comment: combination ID+HASH is different for every of your Clients. So you can't transfer IDs and Hashs this way. Don't spam though. What error is thrown?

Comment: telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.UserIdInvalidError: Invalid object ID for a user. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure that the request is designed for users or otherwise look for a different one more suited (caused by InviteToChannelRequest). This error occur while adding members but if I'm adding from already created list as I show in second code so It didn't give thish error.

Comment: @Apepenkov Could you tell me about the way through which I transfer id and hash from excel to list.

Comment: you can't. You can send message from client A to client B with 
tg://user?id=USER_ID to transfer, but I don't think it will be OK for you

Comment: Remember adding users without their consent is considered spam, and will likely get both the group and account banned.